is $2 \log n +n$ little-o of $n^2$?
I developed an algorithm which runs in $O(n\log n) + O(n\log n) + O(n)$ and I want to check if is little-o of $n^2$, so $o(n^2)$
To be little-of I need to have $2(n\log n) + n < cn^2\; \forall n \geq n_0$
Manipulating this (dividing by $n$) I have $2(\log n) +1 < cn$ for all $n \geq n_0$

Let's say I choose my $n_0 = 2$, on this case it won't be valid since I will have $2\cdot 1 +1 < 2c$ and for $c= 1$ this won't work.

So let's say I choose my $n_0=200$, on this case it won't be valid since I will have $2\cdot 7.6 +1 < c\cdot200$, so $16.2 < 200c$. But for $c = \frac1{200}$ this also do not works.


Therefore can I assume that $2 \log n +n$ is NOT little-o of $n^2$?

I edited some MathJax in. However, you already had $O(n \log_n)$ (except as $O(n log_n)$ yielding $O(n log_n)$); did you mean $O(n \log n)$ instead?

You seem to be a bit mixed up about the definition of little-oh. Can you tell us what definition you are using? Do you know some examples of little-oh behaviour? Have you seen proofs of things being little-oh of something else before?

Yes, sorry, I meant ( log )

I'm trying to study by the Algorithms Design book from Tardos @IzaakvanDongen . As far as I understood on little O, to prove, I can choose the "n" but not the "c" and it has to work for all c >=0

You're essentially playing a game where you need to find $n_0(c)$. But you could also equivalently show that $\lim\frac{f(n)}{n^2}= 0$

On this case ()/$^2$ will always be 0 when n goes to infinity, this I can see (hope is the correct interpretation :) ) But on the game I need to find $0()$, for the case I described, it seems that there is no $0$ that works for any arbitrary $()$, so I supposed the interpretation I've done of ()/$^2$ $ = 0$ was false

What you write is sort of the right idea. A more formal definition is "$f(n) = o(g(n))$ if for every $c > 0$, there is some $n_0$ (depending on $c$) such that for all $n \ge n_0$, we have $|f(n)| \le c|g(n)|$". The key differences are that you must impose $c > 0$, and that $n_0$ does not have to work for all $c$. (In fact, if you strengthen either of those, that would imply $f$ is eventually zero).

Thanks for the explanation but not sure I fully get it.  If is "for every c > 0", how can we state after that "$n0$ does not have to work for all c"? Like in my example, I had chosen 0=200. So on the "game" of choosing c, someone could choose c = 1/200, which is bigger than $0$, so it's fine. Moreover this do not validate the equation  $2(\log n) +1 < cn$ when replacing n by 200 and c by 1/200

The point is that in the "game", the person choosing a $c$ (your "opponent") has to choose first, because of the order of the quantifiers. Then once they have chosen, it's your turn to choose an $n_0$ that works for that $c$. If they choose $c = 1/200$, you can choose $n_0 = 10^{10}$, for example. If you're still not happy, can you please provide the exact definition of $o$ from the book?

Oh!!!! I got it now! They have to choose first!

I can provide the definition but is the same you've sent before. Here you go: the limit 0 ≤ f(n) < cg(n) is valid to all c > 0. Which is, f(n) becomes insignificant when g(n) approches inifinity. ($lim f(n)/g(n) = 0$)

What I was missing was to understand the "opponent" chooses before, that was a great explanation, thank you!

You have to be careful with the order of quantifiers and the definitions of $o$ and $O$.
DEFINITION OF $O$. You have $f(n)=O(g(n))$ if there exists $K>0$ and $n_0>0$ such that for all $n>n_0$, $|f(n)|\leq Kg(n)$.
The quantity you want to evaluate, call it $Q$, seems to have three terms $Q=Q_1+Q_2+Q_3$. You say you proved $Q_1(n)=O(n\log n)$, $Q_2(n)=O(n\log n)$ and $Q_3(n)=O(n)$. So there exists $K_1>0$ and an integer $n_1$ such that if $n>n_1$ then $|Q_1(n)|\leq K_1n\log(n)$. Similarly there exists $K_2>0$ and an integer $n_2$ such that if $n>n_2$ then $|Q_2(n)|\leq K_2n\log(n)$ and there exists $K_3>0$ and an integer $n_3$ such that if $n>n_3$ then $|Q_3(n)|\leq K_3n$.
Now let $n_4=\max(n_1,n_2,n_3)$, then for all $n>n_4$ you have
$$
|Q(n)|\leq|Q_1(n)|+|Q_2(n)|+|Q_3(n)|\leq (K_1+K_2)n\log n+K_3n. 
$$
You know that $\log n$ is bigger than $1$: more precisely, if $n\geq 3$ then $1\leq\log n$ and hence $n\leq n\log n$. So, let $n_0=\max(3,n_1,n_2,n_3)$, then for all $n>n_0$ you have
$$
|Q(n)|\leq|Q_1(n)|+|Q_2(n)|+|Q_3(n)|\leq (K_1+K_2+K_3)n\log n. 
$$
Take $K=K_1+K_2+K_3$, you have proven that your quantity $Q$ satisfies $Q(n)=O(n\log n)$.
The next step is to prove that this is $Q(n)=o(n^2)$.
DEFINITION $o$. We have $f(n)=o(g(n))$ if and only if the limit of $f(n)/g(n)$ at infinity is $0$.
You know the existence of $K>0$ and $n_0$ such that, for all $n>n_0$, $|Q(n)|\leq K n\log n$. This implies that for all $n>n_0$,
$$
\bigl\lvert\frac{Q(n)}{n^2}\bigr\rvert\leq K\frac{\log n}{n}. 
$$
This shows the $Q(n)/n^2$ tends to $0$ since $0$ is the limit of $\log(n)/n$.
Note that this implies that $Q(n)=O(n^2)$ and this is a good training to write the proof of this statement.

Clearly, once you have enough dexterity with all of this you do not write the details any time and know which function is negligible compare to which other one...

Indeed, you can also prove $Q(n)=o(n^{1+\epsilon})$ for any value of $\epsilon>0$.
